# While Loop with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to mimic the while loop of plain Javascript in AngularJS. I simply want to call the createPlant() method x number of times according to the value of the quantity input, when the "add" button is clicked, as follows (it adds to an array 'plants'):

```
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < $("#pQuantity").val()) {
        createPlant();
        i += 1;
    };
```

In Angular I have:

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="addPlant()" type="button">Add</button>
```

And I'm not sure how the script would look but this is what I wrongly put:

**JS**

```
var i = 0;
while (i < $("#pQuantity").val()) {
    $scope.addPlant = function() {
        var plant = {name: $("#pVariety").val()};
        $scope.plants.unshift(plant);
    };
    i += 1;
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a while loop instead of a for loop?

Comment: No reason, whatever works.

Comment: Angular is just JavaScript, so you can use `while` loops just fine. That said, what you're showing is a bad while loop. If you insist on `while`, use `var i=parseInt($("#pQuantity").val()); while(i--) {  ... }`, but you're allocating a variable, and updating it each iteration, so you really want a `for` loop instead, because that's what `for` loops are for.

Comment: why you want to introduce selector based javascript (jQuery) in angular controller..you could have `ng-model` instead reading value using `.val()`

Comment: Advice: remove jQuery from your project and you will understand Angular much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support what @dfsq told you in the comment. Do not use jQuery if you are using angular... unleash the angular power! :P

For your solution, you should do something like this:

Your JS:

```
$scope.result="";
$scope.addPlant = function(){
  for (i=0; i<$scope.someValue;i++){
    //do something
    $scope.result=$scope.result+i.toString()+",";      
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type=number ng-model="someValue" />
  <button ng-click="addPlant()">CLICK ME</button>
  <div>{{result}}</div>
</body>
```

[Plunker sample](https://embed.plnkr.co/cyPUy3dYoDMMBTwn2arx/)